# Wil Paignate : Previous link> 1 of 20 next link>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

I like to display my paginate records like below formats

Previous link> 1 of 20 next link>

where 1 represent page 1 and 20 represent total number of pages.
if I click on next then I like to display below format. 
Previous link> 2 of 20 next link>

I didn't find how to get this in rails 3 using will_paginate.

Thanks for any kind of help.

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```
<%= will_paginate @item, :page_links => false, 
                :separator =>"  #{@item.current_page} of #{@item.page_count}  "%>
```

O/P of this is something like following

```
« Previous 1 of 17 Next »
```

For following o/p

```
Previous link> 1 of 20 next link>
```

You have to do something like following

```
<%= will_paginate @item, :page_links => false, 
                :separator =>"  #{@item.current_page} of #{@item.page_count} ",
                :prev_label => "Previous link>", :next_label => "Next link>" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<%= will_paginate @item, :previous_label => "Previous link", :next_label => "Next Link" %>
```

Cheers!